# Cite in bib latex Chicago style and name of editors

Tags: citing

I want to use Chicago style. I wrote all citation in bib latex file
I used google scholar by writing the title of paper then I chose Chicago but it looks like they are missing usually information about the paper. I have two questions:

- Should I write the citation manually instead of using google scholar help?
- I have a paper edited by two persons in university so when I put the name of university in publisher It didn't appear in citation. Where should I put the university name and the names of people edited the paper?

This is my citation:

```
@article{paskov1996new,
  title={New methodologies for valuing derivatives},
  author={Paskov, Spassimir},
  journal={Mathematics of Derivative Securities,S. Pliska and M. Dempster, eds.},
  pages={545--582 },
  year={1996},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK.}
}
```

Note: I put names of editors with journal 
Do I have to specify Chicago style in  latex file ? I used \bibliographystyle{plain}

Comment: It is very unusual to include the names of a jounal's editors in the `journal` field. What are you trying to achieve? I'm also not aware of a bibliography style that shows the contents of the `publisher` field for entries of type `@article`. If you wanted to help your readers locate the publication in question, you should really make an effort to provide `volume` and `number` fields.

Comment: There are two editors for this paper where should I put there name?

Comment: Your write-up is quite confusing: For articles published in (academic) journals, there are usually authors *but no editors*. Is the entry type `@article` maybe incorrect? Should the entry type maybe be `@incollection`?

Comment: Can you explain me what is the@incollection mean ?

Comment: Please see the answer I posted a short while ago.

Comment: Another thing that's confusing about your write-up is that you mention in the title that you wish to use "Chicago" formatting, but later you write that you employ the `plain` bibliography style. The `plain` style does not, repeat, does not implement "Chcago" style. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that you're using an inappropriate entry type. The `@article` entry type should be used exclusively for articles published in (academic) journals. You ought to be using the `@incollection` entry type, maybe along the following lines:

[image]

You will do yourself a huge service if you take the time to learn what some of BibTeX's many entry types are, learn when to use various types, and especially learn when *not* to use some entry types. Among the commonly encountered entry types are `@article`, `@book`, `@incollection`, `@techreport`, and `@misc`; the latter is the catch-all entry type.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{paskow:97,
  author    = "S. H. Paskow",
  title     = "New methodologies for valuing derivatives",
  year      = 1997,
  pages     = "545--582",
  chapter   = 27,
  booktitle = "Mathematics of Derivative Securities",
  editor    = "M. A. H. Dempster and S. R. Pliska",
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
  address   = "Cambridge,~UK",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{paskow:97}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.